# Efficient assignment into a pandas Series based on a bool Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, boolean, series

given a `Series` of bools, I want to create a new `Series`, which starts from 0, and increments every the corresponding entry in the boolean `Series` is `True`. Here is an example:

```
s = pd.Series([False, True , False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False])
```

which looks like:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8     True
9     False
```

I am looking for an efficient, and if possible elegant, operation, without looping, to obtain the following `Series`:

```
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    3
9    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`pd.Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)

```
s.cumsum()

0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    3
9    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Nice, I knew this function, but thought that it only operates on series of dtypes int or float.

Comment: @splinter `bool` is a sub class of `int`.  `issubclass(bool, int)` evaluates to `True`